# Filter an item and show x number of oldest records for that item

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, filter, delete-row

Friends,
I tried to do some patchwork to resolve my task however not successful (no background in programming). So any help would be appreciated.

Background:
Excel spreadsheet with multiple item IDs, one item can have multiple rows associated with it (Unit Number 1 to N). Each row (Unit number) has a date association (repeating or same). For example:
I've 2000 units of item number 10110014 spanning from 04/22/2022 to 07/07/2022. Also, I've another 500 units of item 10112767 spanning from 05/01 to 7/7. It is a live sheet and data will get added daily.

Task:
I want to generate a list of unit numbers based on 2 input parameters - Item ID and number of units:

1. filter and return the oldest records (based on number of units parameter for the corresponding Item ID)
2. copy these records in a new sheet
3. delete the returned records from the original sheet.

Let me know how can i achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Please be aware that we are not here to do your work. Can you eleborate on how this needs to work, e.g. the process. Does it need to happen on opening the worksheet or is it  a manual process only needed once? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just curious, what did you mean of "_the oldest record_" ? If you mean the id X with the oldest date in DATE column ---> if id X has 20 records with all the same old dates, and you fill "number of units to pick" with 10, then which top 10 oldest records from those 20  records of the same date are ? If you mean the id X with the "smallest" number in Unit Number column, then the question is : do the code need to bother with the date ?

Comment: @Aldert - thank you - i'm not asking for anyone to do my work - This needs to happen after entering two parameters - Item ID and number of units for that item id.  We will be doing this process about 20 times per day.  So far I've been successful with filtering the data by Item ID, and date sorting.  I'm struggling to get the oldest 20 records (even if it's the same date but different unit ID to filter). I was about to copy and paste in a different sheet as well.

Comment: @karma - the process is: User inputs Item ID and Unit count,  the code searches for item id, sorts by oldest to newest date, and filter out the top x (between 1 to 25 variable based on a cell value). If the oldest date is repeated 20 times then those 20 records i'd need. So basically, I'm trying to count rows after filtering the records and finding it hard for a date value.

Comment: So show us your code, what have you done so far? Did you build a form? or are the two user inputs cells? please update your question with the relevant info so we can help you.

Comment: @AJ2022, will the UnitNumber column need to be sorted also ? So, there are 3 level of sorting, with order: (1) ItemID (2) Date (3) UnitNumber. Say for example, after the data is sorted : there are 50 ItemID, 1011014 from row 2 to row 51. Under Date column, row 2 to row 11 is 12 Jul 2022 which the UnitNumber is from 21 to 30 (10 units). Date column row 12 to row 31 is also 12 Jul 2022 which the UnitNumber is from 51 to 70 (20 units) and finally Date column row 32 to row 51 is 14 Jul 2022 which the unit number is from 31 to 50 (20 units). (continue)

Comment: Entered ItemID : 1011014. If Number of Units to Pick is 7, then the expected result : _ItemID 10110014, Date 12 Jul 2022, UnitNumber 21 to 27 (7 units)_. If Number of Units to Pick is 20, then the expected result : _ItemID 10110014, Date 12 Jul 2022, Unit Number 21 to 30 (10 units) and 51 to 60 (10 units)_. Please CMIIW.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy First n Rows from a Filtered Range

- The code needs to be copied to the sheet module of the worksheet whose screenshot is posted in the question, e.g. `Sheet1`, not into a standard module e.g. `Module1`.
- There is nothing to run, the code runs automatically.
- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section.
- The rows might be copied only after changing the value in `B2` that is if the value in `B1` is valid and there are enough items (units).
- You could 'decorate' some of the `Exit Sub` lines (except the last) with an appropriate message box or `Debug.Print` line to not wonder why nothing is happening.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     
    ' Define constants.

    ' Source 
    Const sIdCellAddress As String = "B1"
    Const sUnitsCellAddress As String = "B2"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A4"
    Const sIdColumn As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    ' Turn off any existing filters.
    
    If Me.FilterMode Then Me.ShowAllData
    
    ' Validate the inputs.
    
    Dim iCell As Range: Set iCell = Me.Range(sIdCellAddress)
    Dim uCell As Range: Set uCell = Me.Range(sUnitsCellAddress)
    
    Dim irg As Range
    
    ' Check if the id cell was changed (will not trigger the copy).
    Set irg = Intersect(iCell, Target)
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' to not re-trigger when clearing
            uCell.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub ' the id cell was changed            
    End If

    ' Status: the id cell was not changed!
    
    ' Check if the units cell was changed (may trigger the copy).
    Set irg = Intersect(uCell, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' units cell was not changed
    
    ' Status: the units cell was changed!
    
    ' Check if the id cell is not blank.
    Dim iString As String: iString = CStr(iCell.Value)
    If Len(iString) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' id cell is blank
    
    ' Validate the units cell.
    Dim uValue As Variant: uValue = uCell.Value
    If VarType(uValue) <> vbDouble Then Exit Sub ' is not a number
    If uValue <> Int(uValue) Then Exit Sub ' is not a whole number
    If uValue < 1 Then Exit Sub ' is zero or negative
            
    ' Reference the filtered range ('iscvrg').
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Me.Range(sFirstCellAddress).CurrentRegion
    
    ' Reference the id data column range (no headers).
    Dim iscrg As Range
    Set iscrg = srg.Columns(sIdColumn).Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        
    ' Count the existing items.
    Dim iCount As Long: iCount = Application.CountIf(iscrg, iString)
    If iCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no items
    If iCount < uValue Then Exit Sub ' not enough items
    
    ' Filter the source range.
    srg.AutoFilter sIdColumn, iString
    
    ' Reference the visible cells of the id data column range.
    Dim iscvrg As Range: Set iscvrg = iscrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' Remove the filter.
    Me.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Combine the first n ('uValue') cells into the source union range ('surg').
    
    Dim isCell As Range
    Dim surg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each isCell In iscvrg.Cells
        n = n + 1
        If surg Is Nothing Then
            Set surg = isCell
        Else
            Set surg = Union(surg, isCell)
        End If
        If n = uValue Then Exit For
    Next isCell
    
    ' Reference the destination first cell ('dfCell').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Parent.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim difCell As Range: Set difCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim dlCell As Range
    Set dlCell = difCell.EntireRow.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - difCell.Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    
    Dim dfCell As Range
    
    If dlCell Is Nothing Then
        Set dfCell = difCell
    Else
        Set dfCell = difCell.Offset(dlCell.Row - difCell.Row + 1)
    End If
    
    ' Copy and delete.
    
    With Intersect(surg.EntireRow, srg)
        .Copy dfCell
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' to not re-trigger when deleting
            .Delete xlShiftUp
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```